# java Database framework comparison

Tags: java, database, architecture

I want to create an application that synchronize a database to multiple databases(various type of databases).

I'm looking for a framework that suitable to do this.

I was looking for something just get the Object of the data (like a resultset) then copy that object to the destination database. Or comparing between 2 data.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Start writing - let us know how it turns out.  Bring back some data.

Answer (score 4):

There is a basic choice you need to make between:

- Object-relational mappers (ORMs); or
- SQL-based frameworks.

Each has their merits.

ORMs seek to project an object model onto a database. The choices for this in the Java space are JPA (Java Persistence API) centric. JPA is part of the EJB 3.0 spec and includes cousins like Hibernate. It's great if your data operations are fairly straightforward and you don't need huge throughput. They tend to be complex and memory-intensive however.

SQL based frameworks allow greater throughput and more complex queries but come at a cost: different databases have different SQL dialects. People will often be familiar with SQL and JPA requires another query language. SQL can be used in anything.

In terms of SQL frameworks, much personal favourite is Ibatis.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the difference between ORMs and SQL-based frameworks. That choice is underestimated